# MVC converting images before upload

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, model-view-controller, memorystream

I have an application that uploads images into a blob in azure. My issue is that I need to convert images into Jpeg before the upload. my solution seemed to work, but nothing would get uploaded. Azure shows the name of the blob, but a size of 0B is shown.

```
var pic = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Request.Files[file].InputStream);
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()){
    pic.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(label + ".jpeg");
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream( ms);
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong with this code?

Comment: rewind the memorystream before upload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After writing to a stream you typically have to move the position back to 0 before you can read from it.

Try adding `ms.Position = 0;` before you call `UploadFromStream`

Comment: Thank you. I would never have though of trying to reset the stream position.